# Acer bios menu not loading

Tags: linux, uefi

I was trying to open the bios menu on my Acer nitro 5. I've done this before. The menu was looked like a blank command line.[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q4SQ.jpg)

Comment: What did you do/try?

Comment: I clicked f2 while on the logo.

Comment: I can still boot into things with f12